# Progress greater than 100%

Tags: antd

I want to use an antd Progress to show user calories. And sometimes the user can eat more than he should and the Progress should be greater than 100% and red(failed).
It is possible with antd Progress ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `Progress` Component will check the `percent` props first, only `0 < percent < 100` is permit, you can find the check function in [ant-design's code](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/progress/progress.tsx#L36):

```
const validProgress = (progress: number | undefined) => {
    if (!progress || progress < 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (progress > 100) {
        return 100;
    }
    return progress;
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :D